# Sending Two Separate Rows in an Attachment on an E-mail using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, rows

I'm trying to send the top row in my excel spreadsheet (which has my `Labels`) and the very last row (which is the last entry) in an e-mail coded through `VBA`.

Right now I can only get one row to send. This is the code within my e-mail code:

```
Set Source = Rows(emptyrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) ]
```

How can I add `Rows(1)` to this as well as `Rows(emptyrow)`

Comment: you will need to post more code than the one line to get the best help.  The entire method would probably be best.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a nicer solution, but this is the one that quickly popped into mind:

```
set source = range(Rows(1).address & "," & Rows(emptyrow).address).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Disgusting, but works (if I understood what you needed correctly).

Edit: found another solution:

```
set source = Application.Union(rows(1),rows(emptyrow)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```